# Describing bad Chess moves in Japanese

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm trying to determine natural way(s) to express how certain Chess moves will be advantageous or disadvantageous in a certain position.

> In this position, if you exchange your queen with your opponents rook, you'll be at a disadvantage.

This is my best guess at how to express this:

> この局面ではクイーンと相手のルークを交換したら損するよ。

Other things I can think of are

> 〜しないほうがいい
>   〜得はしない
>   〜立場が悪くなる
>   〜困る

If anyone knows of how I can express getting into a "bad situation" or "a loss" in this context, I'd appreciate it. Other words I might be able to use are 有利 or 不利.

Comment: You could find some examples looking through annotated games such as [this one](http://live.shogi.or.jp/oui/kifu/57/oui201607050101.html).

Comment: Thanks, that is a good reference. However, it looks like the style of speech is a bit different than a person might use when casually speaking, so if anyone knows any simple expressions that don't make me sound like an announcer, that would be good too.

Comment: The example sentence seems a little unnatural, not linguistically but game-wise, I guess you wanted to say "you'll be simply at a disadvantage" or so. If so, I'd go with クイーンとルークの交換は単に損だ.

Comment: @user4092: So my example is grammatically correct but doesn't fit the game? How is the meaning of my sentence different from yours? (I mean the "クイーンとルークの交換" part)

Comment: I meant queen-rook exchange is disadvantageous by default and you won't take that move unless you will get some benefit in another aspect, so if you are to comment something, you'd point out short of that exchangeable benefit.

Comment: Right, I am trying to express the disadvantage of exchanging your queen for the opponents rook, which looses several points. For that case, isn't "クイーンと相手のルークを交換したら損するよ" correct?

Comment: That's just a principle, isn't it? not a uniqueness in a certain scene of the game i.e. この局面では.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions you listed all seem fine to me. But there are other expressions that can be used, with different nuances. These are used mainly for shogi moves, but I believe you can use them also for chess.

Using jargon, in the order of severity:

- ～は大【だい】悪手【あくしゅ】だ
- ～は悪手【あくしゅ】だ
- ～は疑問手【ぎもんしゅ】だ
- ～は緩手【かんしゅ】だ

More vaguely:

- ～は味が悪い
- ～はよくない
- ～は苦しい／～は（後で）苦しくなる
- ～は緩い
- ～はぬるい